# How to change the naming convention on ServiceStack ORMLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to change the naming convention used by ORMLite to create database column ? I'd like to use *ColumnLikeThis* instead of **column_like_that** .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a different naming strategy with:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy= new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
```

Here are some examples of [different naming strategies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/OrmLiteCreateTableWithNamingStrategyTest.cs).

Most Dialects use the default strategy above but other RDBMS providers like PostgreSQL use the more conventional [PostgreSqlNamingStrategy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL/PostgreSqlNamingStrategy.cs).